# ExtJS: starting HtmlEditor defaulting to source

Tags: javascript, extjs, html-editor

I'm using ExtJS 3.2.1 and I need a component almost identical to the bundled **HtmlEditor**, with one exception: it must start editing the HTML source code directly. The reason I don't use a normal **TextArea** is that the user should be able to preview the result of his actions before submitting.

I've tried calling *toggleSourceEdit()*, as per ExtJS documentation, with no success. Debugging, I see that the editor object has the *sourceEditMode* property set to **true**, and the Source Edit button seems as if it was "pressed", but clicking on it does not render the typed HTML, and clicking it again goes to the Source Mode.

I've tried calling *toggleSourceEdit()* after the container *show()* method, on the container *afterLayout* listener and on the editor *afterRender* listener. I've tried also calling it on another button that I added to the container. The result is the same on every try.

The only other option I see is updating ExtJS to 3.3.0, but I haven't seem anything related on the changelogs. Either way, it's going to be my next step. **EDIT:** The app had another problems when updating, we'll make a bigger effort to update later. As of right now, we are using the HtmlEditor in its original setting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

ran into the same problem (using 3.3.0 by the way)

stumbled upon a fix by dumb luck. i have no idea why this works, but second time is the charm. call it twice in a row to achieve the desired effect..

```
HTMLEditor.toggleSourceEdit(true);
HTMLEditor.toggleSourceEdit(true);
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Rather calling toggleSourceEdit(), try to setup the configuration while you create HtmlEditor Object

Answer (score 0):

Using `toggleSourceEdit()` caused some problems for me. One was that this seemed to put the editor somewhere in limbo between source edit and WYSIWYG mode unless I used a timeout of 250ms or so. It also puts the focus in that editor, and I don't want to start the form's focus in the editor, especially since it's below the fold and the browser scrolls to the focused html editor when it opens.

The only thing that worked for me was to extend `Ext.form.HtmlEditor` and then overwrite `toggleSourceEdit`, removing the focus command. Then adding a listener for toggling to the source editor when the component is initialized. This is for Ext 4.1 and up. For older versions, replace `me.updateLayout()` with `me.doComponentLayout()`.

```
var Namespace =  {

SourceEditor: Ext.define('Namespace.SourceEditor', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.HtmlEditor',
    alias: 'widget.sourceeditor',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    toggleSourceEdit: function (sourceEditMode) {
        var me = this,
            iframe = me.iframeEl,
            textarea = me.textareaEl,
            hiddenCls = Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'hidden',
            btn = me.getToolbar().getComponent('sourceedit');

        if (!Ext.isBoolean(sourceEditMode)) {
            sourceEditMode = !me.sourceEditMode;
        }
        me.sourceEditMode = sourceEditMode;

        if (btn.pressed !== sourceEditMode) {
            btn.toggle(sourceEditMode);
        }
        if (sourceEditMode) {
            me.disableItems(true);
            me.syncValue();
            iframe.addCls(hiddenCls);
            textarea.removeCls(hiddenCls);
            textarea.dom.removeAttribute('tabindex');
            //textarea.focus();
            me.inputEl = textarea;
        } else {
            if (me.initialized) {
                me.disableItems(me.readOnly);
            }
            me.pushValue();
            iframe.removeCls(hiddenCls);
            textarea.addCls(hiddenCls);
            textarea.dom.setAttribute('tabindex', -1);
            me.deferFocus();
            me.inputEl = iframe;
        }
        me.fireEvent('editmodechange', me, sourceEditMode);
        me.updateLayout();
    }
})
}
```

Then to use it:

```
Ext.create('Namespace.SourceEditor', {
  /*regular options*/
  listeners: {
    initialize: function(thisEditor) {
            thisEditor.toggleSourceEdit();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
htmlEditor.toggleSourceEdit(true);
```

one time should be enough if you do this listening to the afterrender event of the editor.